# Strange C++ output with boolean pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, boolean

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n = 2;
    string s = "AB";
    bool* xd = nullptr;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 100) {
        if (xd == nullptr) {
            bool tmp = false;
            xd = &tmp;
        }
        cout << "wtf: " << " " << (*xd) << " " << endl;
    }
}
```

When I run this on my own mac with g++ -std=c++17, I get a random integer every time (which is odd since *xd should be a bool). Weirdly enough, this doesn't happen on online IDEs like csacademy and onlinegdb.

Comment: Undefined behavior -- pointer to an out-of-scope variable.

Comment: I see, so since tmp is nested it's out of scope?

Comment: Correct. `tmp` is destroyed once the `if` block is exited, leaving `xd` as a dangling pointer. What value it ends up pointing to is anybody's guess. `xd` still points at the memory where `tmp` _was_, but some other data may be stored in that location.

Comment: Here's the output when compiled with [`-g -fsanitize=address,undefined`](https://godbolt.org/z/K9Y5noaxz). I suggest you use those options when debugging your programs. They are really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> if (xd == nullptr) {
>     bool tmp = false;
>     xd = &tmp;
> }
> ```

`tmp` is an automatic variable. It is destroyed automatically at the end of the scope where the variable is declared. In this case, the lifetime of the object ends when the if-statement ends. At that *point*, the pointer `xd` which pointed to the variable becomes invalid.

> ```
> (*xd)
> ```

Here, you indirect through an invalid pointer. That's something that a program must never do. The behaviour of the program is undefined. The program is broken. Don't do this.